# Ejabberd server not getting started?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, openfire, ejabberd

I have re-installed ejabberd server in my localhost.When i run sudo service ejabberd restart its no getting restarted.Instead its craeting error.The following error is shown in erl_crash.dump.All my configurations in conf file is correct.

Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k

I tried everything also killed process running on same ports.I there anything else to do to solve this issue ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue problem wan with my settings,and then restarted the server 
using sudo service ejabbers restart.It worked